# Python - error thrown when separating data - list index out of range

Tags: python, mysql, beautifulsoup

Scraping Yahoo table for earnings dates with Bs4. My code works until I try to compart the data into cells. The exact error is:

ticker =  cells[1].get_text() IndexError: list index out of range

I thought it was due to the table having an 'a href'...but there's text too.

Ideally the format should look something like:

{'company': '2U Inc', 'ticker': 'TWOU', 'eps_est': '-0.04', 'time': 'after market close'}

How can I achieve something like the above output, what am I missing?

```
from urlparse import urljoin
from urllib2 import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb
import re

#mysql portion
mydb = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',
user= '####',
passwd='#####',
db='testdb')
cur = mydb.cursor()

#def store (company, ticker, eps_est, time):
#    cur.execute('INSERT IGNORE INTO EARN (company, ticker, eps_est, time)  VALUES ( \"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\", \"%s\")',(company, ticker, eps_est, time))
#    cur.connection.commit()

base_url = "https://biz.yahoo.com/research/earncal/today.html"
html = urlopen(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.read().decode('utf-8'),"lxml")
table = soup.find_all('table')
rows = table[6].find_all('tr')

for row in rows[2:]:
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    company = cells[0].get_text()
    ticker =  cells[1].get_text()
    eps_est = cells[2].get_text()
    time =    cells[3].get_text()
    #    store(company, ticker, eps_est, time)
data = {
    'company': cells[0].get_text(),
    'ticker': cells[1].get_link('href'),
    'eps_est': cells[2].get_text(),
    'time': cells[3].get_text(),
}
print data
print '\n'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "dot-notation" to find elements inside other elements. Replace:

```
cells[1].get_link('href')
```

with:

```
cells[1].a.get_text()
```

which should be read as and is equivalent to `cells[1].find("a").get_text()`.

And, you need to skip the last "empty" row as well:

```
for row in rows[2:-1]:
```

Comment: still getting a list index out of range

Comment: Okay, right but now it's skipping to the last row
{'eps_est': u'N/A', 'company': u'Zorlu Enerji Elektrik Uretim AS', 'ticker': u'ZOREN.IS', 'time': u'Time Not Supplied'}

Comment: @citramaillo that's because of your indentation. `data = {...` and `print(data)` should be inside the loop.

Comment: Terrific, would you care to explain a but about the iteration in the

     for row in rows[2:-1]:

Comment: @citramaillo sure, this is called "slicing" and it's a pretty neat functionality in Python. The `[2:-1]` helps to skip the first two and the last row. The first two are header rows of the table, the last row is an empty row that contains no data. Hope that helps.